# The equation formula for a circle laying in an arbitrary plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles, 3d

I know the standard and expanded forms of the equation of the circle in the simple 2d space,

${(x-a)}^2+{(y-b)}^2=r^2$

$x^2-2ax+y^2-2by=c$

So in 3d space what are the equations for a circle laying in an arbitrary plane,
and what is the 3d version of the polar form of the circle equation

$$(a+rcos(t),b+rsin(t))$$

How the two equations (that I mentioned up) look in 3d space and are there more abstractive formulae for the circle equation in more than 3 dimensions?

Comment: You're going to have to make your question a *lot* more focused. Do you mean a sphere? Do you mean a torus? Do you mean a circle lying in an arbitrary plane? @DavidGStork just opted for the last in his answer, but I honestly don't think that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: I mean a circle lying in an arbitrary plane,
Thanks, I will make my question more specified.

Answer (score 3):

Choose a center, ${\bf c}$ and any two orthonormal vectors, ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$ and radius $r$.  The circle so defined is the infinite set:  ${\bf c} + r \cos (\theta) {\bf a} + r \sin (\theta) {\bf b}$ for $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$.

If you're working in $n$-dimensional space, then just choose your orthonormal vectors in that space.

Answer (score 3):

A circle lying in the plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ can be defined by getting a point P(px,py,pz) in that plane and intersecting the plane with the sphere  $(x-px)²+(y-py)²+(z-pz)²=R²$ which is centered at P

That means two equations. There's no one-expression $F(x,y,z)=k$ for a 3D circumference (as it also happens for a 3D straight).

You may think "*get z=f(x,y) from plane and plug it into the sphere*". What you get then is a projection on a horizontal plane, not the plane you want.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful